# How to add uicollectionview inside uicollectionview header

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I need to know how I add a collectionview within the header of the collectionview 'father', I have tried it in several ways but it does not work for me.

something like the following image:

[image: this]

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far? Also, are you sure that you need two separate collection views? Have you tried with only one collection view and use the layout to display the first section as your top row?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a separate `xib` file that will represente your header and than adding the new `collectionView` in it.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain me how?

Answer (score 0):

Go through below steps:-

- Take two nib one for normal cell and one for header cell.
- In Header cell take collection view
- Decide which nib you have to load in cellForRow method using boolean flag or something else.

You need to define your own logic.